# How to concatenate two strings in assembly?

Tags: c

Hello I am trying to concatenate two strings.

I load strings 1, 2, & 3. I need to store the final string in r2.

I load the strings from memory using `ldr` and i can store them using `str`.

*code*

Anyone know effective way to concatenate them? Is adding them like I do above not right? Registers are limited to one byte of data so maybe I am doing something else wrong..

I am a noob.

Comment: Can you write a concat in C? It should look very similar.

Comment: String concatenation isn't done through addition, but by moving (i.e. loading and storing) data. Your `STRING3` doesn't have enough room to hold the result of concatenating `STRING1` and `STRING2`. Also, endianness isn't relevant for string concatenation.

Comment: there is a maximum size for STRING3 which would be 300 chars, forgot to mention that. the combination of STRING1 & STRING2 would be less than or equal to 300 bytes then.

Comment: so whatever algorithm I would need, it would just work with a string no bigger than that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that. I assume your strings aren't NULL terminated because they don't appear to be in your code example.

Also, you'd want to store `STRING1` and `STRING2` in the `.text` section (read only permanent memory), while `STRING3` would go into the `.data` section since it is a buffer in RAM.

```
; Strings aren't \0 terminated (like in C) so we should deal with the size ourselves

mov  r4, #STRING1_SIZE
loop1:
   ldrb r3, [r0], #1   ; Copy STRING1 to STRING3
      strb r3, [r2], #1
      subs r4, #1
      bne  loop1

mov  r4, #STRING2_SIZE
loop2:
   ldrb r3, [r1], #1   ; Copy STRING2 to STRING3
   strb r3, [r2], #1
   subs r4, #1
   bne  loop2

; Done
```

Comment: As for endianness, it does not matter until you load words as bytes or bytes as word.